# i want to create labels with consecutive number in the name

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, label, pyqt5

first of all: its written in Python3.6 with PyQt5.

I want to create labels every time a button is clicked. Right now I m doing this by refering to an function when the button is clicked. I d like to stay this way. My problem is, that every time I push this "add" button the same def starts with a har label and buttons. I would like to create different labels ervery time this function is called.

I would like to do somethin like:

....

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.new_line)

def new_line(self, Form):
   self.label+str(i) = QtWidgets.QLabel()
   self.label_2.setObjectName("labeli")
   self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.labeli)
   i = i + 1
```

.....

but in this case i isnt a running variable because it belongs to the word labeli

```
class Ui_Form(object):






    def Table(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui2Form()
        self.ui.setup2Ui(self.window)
        self.window.show()


    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(628, 196)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.LCDAmount = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(Form)
        self.LCDAmount.setObjectName("LCDAmount")
        #self.new_line(Form)
        self.Knopfe(Form)
        #neue Zeile einfügen



    def new_line(self, Form):
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(188, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.label_2.setText('filename')
        self.pushButton.setText("Browse")
        self.dlt = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.dlt.setObjectName("dlt")
        self.dlt.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 40))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.dlt)
        self.dlt.setText("Delete")
        self.dlt.clicked.connect(self.label_2.close)
        self.dlt.clicked.connect(self.pushButton.close)
        self.dlt.clicked.connect(self.dlt.close)
        self.dlt.clicked.connect(self.LCDupdateM)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openFileNamesDialog)








        # Dialogfeld öffnen
    def openFileNamesDialog(self):    
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Datei öffnen", "C://", "XML only (*.xml)")

        if fname:
            f = str(fname)
            f_path, f_ext, f_desc = f.split('.')
            fsp = f_path.split('/')
            fileName = fsp[len(fsp)-1]

            filePath = f_path
            filePathArray = filePath.split("'")
            self.selectedFile = filePathArray[1] + '.xml'

            print(f)
            print(self.selectedFile)
            print(fileName)
            self.label_2.setText(fileName)

    def Knopfe(self, Form):
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.LCDupdate)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.new_line)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.Table)

    def LCDupdate(self,Form):
        n = self.LCDAmount.intValue()
        n=n+1
        self.LCDAmount.display(str(n))

    def LCDupdateM(self,Form):
        n = self.LCDAmount.intValue()
        n=n-1
        self.LCDAmount.display(str(n))




    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "                                            load your modules"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Add module"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Next"))






if __name__ == "__main__":
    #bttn_clicks = 0
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Form()
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem right now is, that i got an optical working Gui, but in 
def openFileNamesDialog im refering to these created lines and labels, and right now only the last line is updating the label from 'filename' to the really chosen file, because i can not call the others anymore, because they all have the same name.

i hope i was able to explain my problems and wishs and i wouldreally appreciate if someone would help me. 
I m thankful for every helpful comment.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to connect the button signal to the correct label without restructuring the program is to add the label as an argument to `openFileNamesDialog` and in `new_line` connect the `self.pushButton.clicked` signal to a `functools.partial` object. That way you only need to add `from functools import partial` at the top of the script, define `openFileNamesDialog` as

```
def openFileNamesDialog(self, label):
        ....
        label.setText(f)
```

and in `new_line()` replace the last line with

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.openFileNamesDialog, self.label_2))
```